# Get 3 highest values from Map<String,String>

Tags: java, sorting, collections, dictionary

I have a `Map<String,String>` which has entries like "User1","43". Now I want a "Top 3" of the highest values.

It would be easier with a `Map<String,Integer>`, but due to technical limitations I can just grab the Map as a `<String,String>`.

What's the most efficient way to convert a `<String,String>` map to a `<String,Int>` one and then sort it?

Answer (score 3):

To convert from `<String, String>` to `<String, Integer>` you can use:

```
 Map<String, Integer> treemap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
 for (Entry<String, String> entry : entries) {
     treemap.put(entry.getKey(), Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue()));
 }
```

However, then you will have to iterate the Map again. If you don't need the whole map, but rather just the top 3, then you can simply iterate the entries and get the top three by comparison.

Or you can reverse the key and value and use a `TreeMap<Integer, String>` with a `Comparator`, if you need both the top elements and the whole data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways:

1. Create SortedMap, e.g. TreeMap with a custom -anonymous- Comparator which performs comparisons by looking up the keys it gets in the compare() method call against the values in the original map.
2. Populate it with all key/value entries in the original through addAll() method.
3. Watch the map being sorted by value.
4. Grab the head/tail (depending on how your comparator sorts)

Similar to above:

1. Create a TreeSet of keys with a custom comparator as above...
2. Populate it with the keySet() of your original map.
3. Grab the head/tail set of the keys.
4. Create a new Map from those keys and value from the original map...

Answer (score 1):

You could just put the values in a List and sort it:

```
ArrayList<Integer> highest = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String value : map.values()) {
    highest.add(Integer.parseInt(value));
}
Collections.sort(highest);
for(int i = highest.size() - 1; i >=0 && i > highest.size()-4; i--){
    System.out.println(highest.get(i));
}
```

If the map is very large it might be better to iterate through it and only select the 3 highest values without sorting the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the values of the Map (with Map.values()), converting each to an Integer (with Integer.getInteger(String s)), and keeping track of the top 3 you see.

Or, you could do as above but instead of keeping track of the top 3, make a LinkedList and insert each Integer at the correct place (traverse the LinkedList until you find where the Integer should be inserted).